# Change wireframe modifier to only show rings

Tags: node-editor, geometry, wireframe

I use geometry nodes to create a cylinder, deform it with a noise texture and then add the wireframe modifier. What I want to achieve is (given the cylinder is in Z direction)that I have wireframe rings by deleting all the edges in Z direction.

[image]

How can this be done with geometry nodes or the wireframe modifier?

Comment: What's the reason for making a cylinder in the first place? If you need rings, why don't you make only rings in the first place?

Comment: I stuck to the cylinder, because I knew how to deform it, make it narrow in the end and also bend it (as shown in the render: https://imgur.com/a/FNivVFA)
I don't know how I can achieve the same results with rings.

Comment: @enats  A lot of the effect in your reference depends on occlusion / shadows. Do you want to retain those?

Comment: Yes, I want to maintain the occlusion / shadows.

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily make some rings only instead of the cylinder in the first place:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a shader would be a flexible and economical approach to this..

A given curve can be bevelled. shaped, and displaced in Geometry Nodes. ( A *Displacement* modifier isn't available on a curve)

[image]

The GN group stores the curve's U, 0-1 along its length. That can be used by a material to paint rings around the tunnel:

[image]

The shader includes a few nodes for varying the ring-scale along the length of the tunnel, perhaps to aid forced perspective.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin! Can I somehow apply this shader to my existing cylinder I created via geometry nodes? What would be the equivalent attribute like "Spline Parameter" or workflow?

Comment: Maybe the Z of the cylinder captured before deformation? Hard to be sure.. go ahead and share on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?